# How to debug a remote application,which does not support java plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash

My application does not support next generation java plug in, but in one of my document i see steps to debug this application to set jvm runtime parameter as -Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y .

Now the problem is with this parameter Internet Explorer is either crashing or hanging without loading anything. once removing this parameter solves this problem and application is running fine.

So is this possible to debug this application with some other parameter? i tried -Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,server=y,suspend=y    also but not working.

Could anyone please guide me debug this remotely? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Can you please explain what do you understand by remote debugging? Once you put above mentioned parameters, you would need to start the debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it is not your internet explorer that is hanging, but your application is not giving a response.

```
Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y
```

If we look at the last option, the name already shows you why there is no longer a response: suspend=y tells the JVM to wait with starting your application till a debugger attaches itself. So, changing this to suspend=n will solve your problem and you can attach your debugger later as the need arises.